# MVC/iis express failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an error when trying to run MVC application in both visual studio 2015/2017.

I know it's not the code because a it's producing the 500 status on the default template, and works fine on the servers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWTbh.jpg

The above screen shot is from chrome, and i have tried it on all of the standard browsers.

I have also tried reinstalling iis and i am still getting the same issue, and have been trying to resolve it for best part of a day. any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Click the Network tab and inspect the response. It'll contain an error message.

Comment: Just says Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error on the network tab as well for the resources in question.  

http://imgur.com/a/NDciu

Comment: Those are the headers. Click the Response tab.

Comment: Just states

Failed to load response data :(


MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS,
AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST, HttpStatus  401, Access is denied.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever find the cause? It's odd that it isn't completely regular, bootstrap.css comes down but my BootSwatch css doesn't. Also all 500 server errors. I'm on a Mac with Parallels, reboot of the VM didn't work. About to try full reboot.

Comment: I had to elevate my vs to local admin, then it worked.